# C#, using static with const

Tags: c#

In the following code what is difference between Field1 and Field2 variables, both can be accessed in static way.

> ```
> public static class FieldName
> {
>     public static const string Field1 = "Field1";
>     public const string Field2 = "Field2";
> }
> ```

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: this doesn't compile for me: The constant 'ConsoleApplication.Program.FieldName.Field1' cannot be marked static

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`error CS0504: The constant 'FieldName.Field1' cannot be marked static`.

> All constants declarations are implicitly static, and the C# specification states that the (redundant) inclusion of the static modifier is prohibited. I believe this is to avoid the confusion which could occur if a reader were to see two constants, one declared static and one not - they could easily assume that the difference in specification implied a difference in semantics.

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/why-can-t-i-use-code-static-code-and-code-const-code-together.aspx

Comment: yes the error is on compile time but while typing code it did not show any error so got confused.